# Alguien puede explicarme este código

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, lambda

Me gustaría saber que hace este código, de la manera mas sencilla posible y una explicación de porque hacerlo así, ¿por mejor practica?

```
 public string Action
    {
        get
        {
            Expression<Func<GigsController, ActionResult>> updateExpression = (c => c.Update(this));
            Expression<Func<GigsController, ActionResult>> createExpression = (c => c.Update(this));

            var action = (Id != 0) ? updateExpression : createExpression;

            return (action.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method.Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Disculpa, se supone que tu tienes un código hecho por ti, y encontraste este?

Comment: Estoy siguiendo un curso, y me tope con esto, y no logro entenderlo muy bien ya investigue un poco pero es muy confuso para mi, me gustaría contar con el apoyo de alguien con mas experiencia y así saber que y el porque de este codigo

Comment: lecturas recomendadas: https://www.dotnetperls.com/func  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P60pt5xlms0 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/func-delegate-using-lambda-expression-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: por cierto, si andas iniciando con ASP.net MVC, te recomiendo este workshop que hice hace unos meses: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: Gracias Amigo! lo tomare en cuenta.

Comment: no le veo mucho sentido al codigo, ambos devolveras como resultado "Update"

Answer (score 3):

El codigo que muestras permite asignar dinamicamente mediante el uso de una expression que accion invocar

Ahora lo que no tendria mucho sentido es devolver el nombre del metodo, se supone que si asignas dinamicamente una accion u otra es para ejecutarla

```
Func<GigsController, bool> compileExp = action.Compile();

ActionResult result = compileExp.Invoke(this);
```

la idea es ejecutar la expresion que se determina segun el valor del Id

[How to: Execute Expression Trees (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654265.aspx)

Aunque quizas no necesites de un Expression<> si la idea es resolver un metodo dinamico para ejecutar, solo usarias

```
Func<GigsController, ActionResult> update = (c => c.Update(this));
Func<GigsController, ActionResult> create = (c => c.Create(this));

var action = (Id != 0) ? update : create;

ActionResult result = action(this);
```